# No route matches [POST] '/users/new'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qZYF2Wz1qM8.
I'm on about the 39 minute mark and i have and error saying No route matches [POST] i feel like there is a simple solution to this problem could anyone help?

I am on mac using postgresql, VS code

this is my new.html.erb file

```
<h1> Sign Up </h1>

 <%= form_tag('/users/new', method: 'POST') do %>
  <p>Username: <%= text_field_tag(:username) %> </p>
   <p>Password: <%= password_field_tag(:password) %> </p>
    <%= submit_tag  'Register' %>
 <% end %>
```

this is my routes file

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
         resources :users, only: [:new, :create, :show]
      resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
      root :to => 'static#welcome'
    # For details on the DSL available within this file, see 
   http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
    end
```

I have another error GET sessions could anyone perhaps help this is mu new.html.erb file

```
<h1> Log in </h1>
  <%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
    <p>Username: <%= text_field_tag(:password) %></p>
     <p>Password: <%= password_field_tag(:password) %></p>
      <%= submit_tag 'Log In' %>
       <% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `rake routes` in your console, you'll see (amongst other things):

```
    users POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
 new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
     user GET    /users/:user_name(.:format)    users#show
```

As you can see, there is no route with the HTTP verb `POST` with the url `/users/new` (there is, however, a route with the url `/users/new` with the HTTP verb `GET`, as you can also see). Which is why you're getting the error you're getting.

But, you can see that you have the url `/users` with the HTTP ver `POST`. And, that's pointing to your `users#create` action which is, presumably, what you want. And, you can also see that it has a named helper called `users`. Which use you by appending `_path` (in most cases). Like `users_path`.

So, instead of doing:

```
<%= form_tag('/users/new', method: 'POST') do %>
```

... you should do

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: 'POST' do %>
```

EXCEPT! When specifying a method, I like to do it more like:

```
<%= form_tag users_path, method: :post do %>
```

EXCEPT! A form constructed with a `form_tag` as above is going to submit using `POST` by default. So, instead, what you really should do is:

```
<%= form_tag users_path do %>
```

And that should get you going in the right direction.

BTW, you might want to bookmark and review the [Rails Routing from the Outside In](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). I still refer to it all the time.

Comment: You should really post a new question - because it's a new problem. Also, you should (1) format your code with care and (2) include your stack trace (from your console) in your question so we can see more completely what is happening.